# Elementary Question: How to see a variable value by hovering or clicking on it on Ride

Tags: robotframework-ide

I'm very new to RIDE & RF. I have a test suite in a file with several test cases and all variables values have been defined in **another file** on another Folder. When i'm on Edit Interface of RIDE and i choose a keyword and i click on CTRL button at the same time and MAINTAIN it, i can view the definition of that Function.
2 questions:

1-How can I view that Keyword on the same page without maintaining the CTRL button?

2- How can I view the value of that scalar variable without Opening the other file? because it adds a lot of "goings to the data file and comings" to the test file.
I can't change the files/folders structure because it's not mine.
Is there any way to see variables values?

Thanks in advance for any insight

Answer (score 0):

None of those features do exist.

1 - Is the first time it was requested

2 - Exists an [issue](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/issues/306) (from 2009, early days of RIDE):

```
It would be nice to get possibility to see variable's content by pressing
Ctrl key. It should work similar to Keyword documentation look-up. For
example, I have variable called ${output_dir}. It is configured in Variable
section as let say 'C:\output'. So I would like to get this in a pop-up
window by pressing Ctrl key.
It could be great if it handle also nested variables. E.g. if my
{drive_letter}\output}' and there is separately defined
variable ${drive_letter}='C:' it should be correctly solved as 'C:\output'.
```